# Swift Table View Cell Changing Data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

I have table view controller. My problem; The cell in my table view changes every time I enter the view controller. For example; There are 2 data (address-1 and address-2). The first row is address-1, the second row is address-2, when I re-enter the page, the cells change.  How can I fix this problem. Thanks

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import MapKit
class DenemeTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var ref: DatabaseReference!
let user: User = Auth.auth().currentUser!
var adresListesi = [Adresler]()
var adres: Adresler!
@IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.table.delegate = self
    self.table.dataSource = self
    Adresdefteri()
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    Adresdefteri()
    table.reloadData()
}
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return adresListesi.count
}
  //prob.   
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DenemeTableViewCell
    let adresList = self.adresListesi[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = adresList.adresname
    return cell
}
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath:IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "DENEMEHARİTAGO", sender: indexPath.row)
}
 func Adresdefteri() {
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    let adreslerim = ref
    adreslerim?.child("locations").child(user.emailWithoutSpecialCharacters).child("Adresler").observe( .value) { [self] (snapshot) in
        if let gelenVeributunu = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
            self.adresListesi.removeAll()
             for gelenSatirVerisi in gelenVeributunu {
                if let sozluk = gelenSatirVerisi.value as? NSDictionary {
                    let key = gelenSatirVerisi.key
                    let adresname = sozluk["adresname"] as? String ?? ""
                    let latitude = sozluk["latitude"] as? Double ?? 0.0
                    let longitude = sozluk["longitude"] as? Double ?? 0.0
                    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
                    let adres = Adresler(adresname: adresname, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, adresid: key)
                    self.adresListesi.append(adres)
                }
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.table.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

[tableview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApQYc.png)

Comment: Your adresListesi is an array that gets its value from snapshot in Database call, which is dictionary and dictionary are unordered, so they append elements in random order. Which is what you see on table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the data source array after creating it and reloading the table view, that way it stays consistent. Cheers!

```
    self.arrayName = arrayName.sorted(by: { $0.valueToSortByInArray > $1.valueToSortByInArray })
```

Comment: Thanks for answer Sharma and Mishka. Can you show me code on solution, Mishka. Because I tried, but still have problem

Comment: Edited the answer, let me know if it works or makes sense!

Comment: Arrayname is now coming consistent. But when I go into it, the other data's info comes in.

Comment: When I click on the cell, random data comes up. How can I solve this situation @Mishka, any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean? In your didSelectRowAt which gets called when you click on the cell you should be performing a segue.. what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The problem was somehow resolved. Thanks for your patience and help.

Comment: @EmreAtalan If my answer has been of help to you, please mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to sort the adresListesti to make sure the order is consistent.
An example would be:

```
adresListesi.sort { $0.adresname < $02.adresname }
```

Put that right before `DispatchQueue.main.async` and it should work.